# Errors with fetch() but not with ajax or axios

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios, fetch-api

So I'm trying to send data to an api, and after many hours I have it working in ajax and axios, but cannot for the life of me get fetch to work.

```
// Base variables
const data = { name: "test", email: "test@test.com" }
const url = "https://dev.xxx.xxx/contactform/";
const method = "POST";

// Ajax
$.ajax({
  type: method,
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: res => console.log(res),
  error: err => console.error(error.message)
});

// Axios
axios.post(url, data, {headers:{}})
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(e => console.error(e.message));

// Fetch
await fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    mode: "no-cors",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(e => console.error(e.message));
```

And here are the outputs:
[image]

Server side actions also confirm the first two work.

Things I've tried:

- Changing fetch mode to "cors" returns a CORS error: `Access to fetch at 'https://dev.xxx.xxx/contactform/' from origin 'https://cdpn.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field cache-control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`
- Changed accept and content-type headers to text, x-www-form-urlencoded, json, and removed them too.
- Removed the data, stringified it, left it an object, and replaced it with just text

Can anyone tell me if there is some fundamental reason why this isn't working or if I'm missing something from my Fetch call?

**SOLVED: The issue was a combination of mismatched things but in short it was fixed with the above config and changing mode to "cors"**

Comment: Try `body: JSON.stringify(data)`. It looks like the issue (415) is related to media type and I wonder if this is why.

Comment: First understand what CORS is. Very good intro here: https://twitter.com/b0rk/status/1162392625057583104?s=20

Comment: Thanks @JamieDixon - I have tried that and said so in my 3rd dot point, but to no avail. But exactly what I thought with the 415 error.

Comment: Awesome graphic @ArupRakshit - and I do understand it (at least as far as that graphic goes), but Ajax and Axios do not run into a cors error ever, and fetch only does if I explicitly tell it to look for it under mode. You sound like you may know more than me though so any other ideas?

Comment: @JamieDixon seems to be right. Please update your code to show us exactly the configuration you tried for sending JSON text

Comment: Updated the code to show how I tried sending JSON text. Received the exact same error, but then I changed mode back to cors as well and it worked! I thought I had tested it but obviously not.

Answer (score 0):

Using fetch you will need to add a header to the response in your server code:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://cdpn.io
```

This is quite common when using fetch. There is one more option you can try, but I don't recommend it:

Use an IP instead of a URL

```
const url = "https://192.0.0.1/contactform/";
```

When using fetch, be aware of browser compatibility:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Compatibility_com_os_browsers

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does Fetch obey cors more strictly than Axios/Ajax? I added this in previously and removed the cors errors for Axios and Ajax - but not for fetch?

Comment: Yes, fetch api follow the same-origin policy, this means that a web application using those APIs can only request HTTP resources from the same origin the application was loaded from, unless the response from the other origin includes the right CORS headers.

See more about:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: So to help me cement my understanding, Ajax and axios do not follow this policy? Which is why they are allowed through by the browser when fetch is not?

Comment: @chisnall.io No, the same-origin policy is imposed by the browser on all three of them, and works the same. This is not the correct answer.

Comment: @chisnall.io I researched about and the Bergi answer is correct.